# Redis Configuration in Remote Server

Tags: redis

After several times googling I am posting this issue which is with me till 5 days. I have a cloud server where I installed the redis server . I want to connect that redis server through my c# code. I have tried many times with it but failure with my code.

I am confusing about the binding configuration , which ip address should I put in bind XX.XX.XX.XXXX. The servers ip address or my development machine ip address.

Error raised:
 Socket Failure on PING

```
 private static Lazy<ConfigurationOptions> configOptions = new Lazy<ConfigurationOptions>(() =>
    {
        var configOptions = new ConfigurationOptions();
        configOptions.EndPoints.Add("192.XXX.XXX.XXX:6379");
        configOptions.ClientName = "ATLDCYZ082158";
        configOptions.ConnectTimeout = 100000;
        configOptions.AbortOnConnectFail = false;
        configOptions.Ssl = false;
        configOptions.SyncTimeout = 100000;
        return configOptions;
    });
```

private static ConnectionMultiplexer conn;

```
    private static ConnectionMultiplexer LeakyConn
    {
        get
        {
            if (conn == null || !conn.IsConnected)
                conn = GetConnectionMultiplexer();
            return conn;
        }
    }



private static ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnectionMultiplexer()
    {
        var sw = new StringWriter();
        try
        {              

           var connectionMultiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(configOptions.Value, sw);
           var log = sw.ToString();
           return connectionMultiplexer;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var log = sw.ToString();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: `configOptions.EndPoints.Add("192.XXX.XXX.XXX:6379");` shold be redis server endpoint. If you still fail, check if any network firewall exists in the cloud which is restricting the 6379 port.

Comment: which endpoint name I have to put in "bind" in service.conf?